# Child component not re-rendering with changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components that are both children of the same parent component that both render a list of places - a map that loads the places as markers on the map and then a grid of place listings with a filter menu. What I want to do is communicate the filter click from the place listing component to the map component to filter the markers. To accomplish this I have a function in the parent component called handlePlaceFilter() that I am passing into the place listing child component as a prop.

I am able to trigger a console log statement from the parent component after a filter click on the child and can pass up to the parent a filtered list of places - but I can't get it to re-render either component with the filtered list of places.

Here's the parent component containing both children and the handlePlaceFilter() function:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import MapContainer from './MapContainer';
import _ from 'lodash';
import Places from './Places';
const Cosmic = require('cosmicjs')();

export default class PlaceIndex extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.handlePlaceFilter = this.handlePlaceFilter.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            destination: '',
            destinations: '',
            places: '',
            globals: '',
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const bucket = Cosmic.bucket({
            slug: 'where-she-goes',
            read_key: '',
            write_key: ''
        });
        try {
            let result = await bucket.getBucket()
            this.setState (() => {
                return {
                    destination: _.find(result.bucket.objects, { slug: this.props.match.params.slug }),
                    destinations: _.filter(result.bucket.objects, {type_slug: 'destinations'}),
                    places: _.filter(result.bucket.objects, {type_slug: 'places'}),
                    globals: _.filter(result.bucket.objects, {type_slug: 'globals'})
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    handlePlaceFilter (places) {
        
        console.log("Place filter clicked!")
        console.log(places)
        this.setState (() => {
            return {
                places: places
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.places || !this.state.destination)
            return <p>Loading...</p>

        // compile list of destination plus children
        let placeDestinations = new Array();
        placeDestinations.push(this.state.destination.slug);
        this.state.destination.metadata.child_destinations &&
        this.state.destination.metadata.child_destinations.map(destination => {
            placeDestinations.push(destination.slug)
            destination.metadata.child_destinations &&
            destination.metadata.child_destinations.map(child_destination => {
                placeDestinations.push(child_destination.slug)
            })
        })
        console.log("Destination List")
        console.log(placeDestinations)

        // filter places by destination list

        let places = this.state.places.filter(function(place) {
            return placeDestinations.includes(place.metadata.destination.slug);
        })
        console.log("Places")
        console.log(places)

        let destinationCenter = {
            latitude: this.state.destination.metadata.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.destination.metadata.longitude
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Header 
                    destinations={this.state.destinations}
                    globals={this.state.globals}
                />
                <div className="places-title text-center">
                    <h2>All Places in {this.state.destination.title}</h2>
                </div>
                <MapContainer 
                    places={places} 
                    center={destinationCenter}
                />
                <Places 
                    places={places}
                    handlePlaceFilter={this.handlePlaceFilter}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here's the child component for the Place Listings:

```js
import React from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'

export default class Places extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.showHotels = this.showHotels.bind(this);
        this.showAll = this.showAll.bind(this);
        this.showRestaurants = this.showRestaurants.bind(this);

        let places = _.flatMap(this.props.places, this.props.places.metadata);
        var allplaces = new Array();
        var hotels = new Array();
        var restaurants = new Array();
        var sights = new Array();

        places &&
        places.map(place => {
            allplaces.push(place)
            if (place.metadata.place_type == 'Hotel') {
                hotels.push(place)
            }
            if (place.metadata.place_type == 'Restaurant') {
                restaurants.push(place)
            }
            if (place.metadata.place_type == 'Sight') {
                sights.push(place)
            }
        })

        // Limit # of places in each array to customize for page contect

        if (this.props.limit) {
            (allplaces.length > 0) ? (allplaces.length = this.props.limit) : allplaces;
            (hotels.length > 0) ? (hotels.length = this.props.limit) : hotels;
            (restaurants.length > 0) ? (restaurants.length = this.props.limit) : restaurants;
            (sights.length > 0) ? (sights.length = this.props.limit) : sights;
        }

        this.state = {
            current: "All",
            places: allplaces,
            hotels: hotels,
            restaurants: restaurants,
            sights: sights,
            allplaces: allplaces
        }
    }

    showAll (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.handlePlaceFilter(this.state.allplaces);
        this.setState (() => {
            return {
                current: "All",
                places: this.state.allplaces
            }
        });
    }

    showHotels (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.handlePlaceFilter(this.state.hotels);
        this.setState (() => {
            return {
                current: "Hotels",
                places: this.state.hotels
            }
        });
    }

    showRestaurants (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.handlePlaceFilter(this.state.restaurants);
        this.setState (() => {
            return {
                current: "Restaurants",
                places: this.state.restaurants
            }
        });
    }

    showSights (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.handlePlaceFilter(this.state.sights);
        this.setState (() => {
            return {
                current: "Sights",
                places: this.state.sights
            }
        });
    }

    render () {
        if (this.state.allplaces.length > 0) {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <div className="blogFilter text-center text-uppercase">
                                <ul className="list-inline">
                                    <li>{(this.state.current == "All") ? <a href="#" onClick={this.showAll} className="current">All</a> : <a href="#" onClick={this.showAll}>All</a>}</li>
                                    <li>{(this.state.hotels.length > 0) ? ((this.state.current == "Hotels") ? <a href="#" className="current"  onClick={this.showHotels}>Hotels</a> : <a href="#" onClick={this.showHotels}>Hotels</a>) : <span></span>}</li> 
                                    <li>{(this.state.restaurants.length > 0) ? ((this.state.current == "Restaurants") ? <a href="#" className="current"  onClick={this.showRestaurants}>Restaurants</a> : <a href="#" onClick={this.showRestaurants}>Restaurants</a>) : <span></span>}</li>
                                    <li>{(this.state.sights.length > 0) ? ((this.state.current == "Sights") ? <a href="#" className="current"  onClick={this.showSights}>Sights</a> : <a href="#" onClick={this.showSights}>Sights</a>) : <span></span>}</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="blogContainer">
                                    {
                                        this.state.places &&
                                        this.state.places.map(place => {
                                            console.log("Places")
                                            console.log(place)
                                            return (
                                                <div className="col-sm-3 design">
                                                    <article className="portfolio portfolio-2 post-grid">
                                                        <div className="post-thumb">
                                                            <a href={`/place/${place.slug}`}><img src={place.metadata.hero.imgix_url} alt="" /></a>
                                                            <div className="post-thumb-overlay text-center">
                                                                <div className="text-uppercase text-center">
                                                                    <a href="single-portfolio.html"><i className="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                                                    <a href={place.metadata.hero.imgix_url} ><i className="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div className="post-content">
                                                            <header className="entry-header text-center text-uppercase">
                                                                <h6><a href={`/place/${place.slug}`}>{place.metadata.place_type}</a></h6>
                                                                <h2 className="entry-title"><a href=" ">{place.title}</a></h2>
                                                            </header>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </article>
                                                </div>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div></div>
            )
        }

    }

}
```

And here's the child component for the Map:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '300px'
};

let geocoder;

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.onMarkerClick = this.onMarkerClick.bind(this);
    this.displayMarkers = this.displayMarkers.bind(this);
    let addresses = new Array();
    this.props.places &&
      this.props.places.map(place => {
        addresses.push(place.metadata.address)
    })
    this.state = {
        lat: this.props.center.latitude,
        lng: this.props.center.longitude,
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: {},
        selectedPlace: {},
        places: [],
        addresses: addresses
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.plotPoints()
  }

  plotPoints () {
    let locations = this.getPoints(geocoder)
    let places = new Array()

    Promise.all(locations)
    .then((returnVals) => {
      returnVals.forEach((latLng) => {
        let place = {
          latitude: latLng[0],
          longitude: latLng[1]
        }
        places.push(place)
      })
      console.log("Places to Plot:")
      console.log(places[0].latitude)
      // places now populated
      this.setState(() => {
        return {
          lat: places[0].latitude,
          lng: places[0].longitude,
          places: places
        }
      });
      console.log("Center Lat")
      console.log(this.state.lat)
      console.log(this.state.lng)
    });
  }

  getPoints(geocoder) {
    let locationData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.addresses.length; i++) {
      locationData.push(this.findLatLang(this.state.addresses[i], geocoder))
    }
    return locationData // array of promises
  }

  findLatLang(address, geocoder) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          console.log(results);
          resolve([results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()]);
        } else {
          reject(new Error('Couldnt\'t find the location ' + address));
        }
      })
    })
  }

  displayMarkers (stores) {
    return stores.map((place, index) => {
      return <Marker key={index} id={index} position={{
       lat: place.latitude,
       lng: place.longitude
     }}
     onClick={() => console.log("You clicked me!")} />
    })
  }

  onMarkerClick (props, marker, e) {
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    geocoder = new this.props.google.maps.Geocoder();
    console.log("Place Array")
    console.log(this.state.places)
    return (
      <div className="container place-map">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <Map
              google={this.props.google}
              zoom={8}
              style={mapStyles}
              initialCenter={{
                lat: this.state.lat,
                lng: this.state.lng
              }}
              
            >
              {this.displayMarkers(this.state.places)}
              <InfoWindow
                marker={this.state.activeMarker}
                visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
              >
                <div>Your Location Here!</div>
              </InfoWindow>
            </Map>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyCOJDrZ_DXmHzbzSXv74mULU3aMu3rNrQc'
})(MapContainer);
```

Comment: Mind putting any of the child component's code?

Comment: Just updated and added in the child components code. I already hacked something together to filter the Place Listings within the child component, my big problem is that I can't communicate that filtered list of places to the map to filter the markers.

Comment: Please remove the API keys from code

Answer (score 0):

In your Child component, you are retrieving/setting places  value in constructor.  After which any change in props of `Parent` component wont notify to `Child` component that state value is updated, unless you add [getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

In this method, you will receive new props and update state from newly received props.

After updating state here (with setState, your child component's render method will execute)

Comment: I did some googling on getDerivedStateFromProps and tried adding the below to the Map child component but it didn't change anything:

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.places !== state.places) {
      return {
        places: props.places,
      };
    }

    // Return null if the state hasn't changed
    return null;
  }

Comment: Is the method itself running?  Which version of react are you using?

Comment: Conceptually you got the idea that why isnt child getting new values?  Child's state isnt updating when parent updates its props.

Comment: Conceptually I get it but I'm struggling with the actual implementation. I'm running react 16, I changed it to set state and its still not working. It doesn't look like getDerivedState is even being triggered if I add a log statement:

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.places !== state.places) {
      console.log("getDerivedState Triggered!")
      this.setState(() => {
        return {
          places: props.places
        }
      });
    }

    // Return null if the state hasn't changed
    return null;
  }

Comment: Can you pull a page with a hosted version of it? fiddle type bit?

Answer (score 0):

For component to rerender and display the changes the state needs to update. Right now youbare update the state with initial props. When the props changes the state of your child component won't change as you are using only initial props. So what you can do is use a lifecycle hook `componentWillReceiveProps`  and inside that update your state with new props.
Code can be something like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(this.state.lat !== nextProps.center.latitude){
    this.setState({ lat: nexrProps.center.latitude});
  }
}
```

You can do likewise for rest of the variables too.
This way whenever your props changes your state will also change thus forcing your component to rerender and reflect the changes.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: If I add the code below it re-renders the map but now without any markers on it:

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(this.state.places !== nextProps.places){
      this.setState(() => {
        return {
          places: nextProps.places
        }
      });
    }
  }

Comment: The map function that you are implementing on places should not be inside contructor. Ideally your constructor should only have state and function bindings. You can move that code to `componentDidMount` and see if it works.

Comment: Also u do not need to pass a function to setState as an argument u can directly pass teh object instead of returning it from function. It will make your code a little more compact.